# its trait bounds were not satisfied label: method `serialize` not found for this struct

Tags: rust, serialization, solana-program-library

I'm trying to save AccountInfo in a struct that #[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Clone, Debug)] to send SOL to this account. AccountInfo is a struct in library that don't impl serialize method. This account is randomly chosen from a map in contract so I cannot pass it into data to make instructions. This is the code:

```
#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct State<'a> {
    pub owner: AccountInfo<'a>,
}
```

Comment: From the [source of the serialize macro](https://docs.rs/borsh-derive-internal/0.9.3/src/borsh_derive_internal/struct_ser.rs.html#28) you can see to derive `BorshSerialize` all fields that are not `borsh_skip`ped have to implement `BorshSerialize`, and that's a common requrement for derives. You'll have to implement `BorshSerialize` and `BorshDeserialize` by hand.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @cafce25! But when I try to impl BorshSerialize for AccountInfo, the compiler said "only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for types defined outside of the crate" and AccountInfo is a type that is defined in another library, which is outside of the crate. So this is a dead end or am I wrong?

Comment: You misunderstood, you'll have to implement them for `State`